# Nullable DateTime? to DateTime convertion doesn't work

Tags: datetime, casting, null, nullable, type-conversion

I have a DOB property defined in my member class as a nullable DateTime?:

```
public DateTime? DOB
{
    get
    {
        var o = base.GetPropertyValue("memberDOB");
        if (o == DBNull.Value)
        {
            return null;
        }
        return (DateTime?)o;
    }
    set
    {
        base.SetPropertyValue("memberDOB", value);
    }
}
```

When the value is null and I'm trying to check if it's nullable - it just keeps saying the cast is not valid:

```
if((DateTime)_currentProfile.DOB == null)
    txtDOB.Text = _currentProfile.DOB.ToString();
```

I tried with

```
TryParse(_currentProfile.DOB.ToString(), out dob)

_currentProfile.DOB == null

_currentProfile.DOB.ToString()

(DateTime)_currentProfile.DOB
```

Neither of them work - it always says cast is not valid.

Don't quite understand why.

Any ideas? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't just cast a Nullable  `DateTime` to a `DateTime` like that. It will break when it's null.

Use `DateTime.HasValue`, and `DateTime.Value` if it returns true.

Answer (score -1):

You are casting to `DateTime`, which is a [*value type*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t63sy5hs.aspx) and cannot be `null`, ever.

Cast to `DateTime?` if you wish to check for `null`, or rather, don't cast but check directly on it:

```
if(_currentProfile.DOB.HasValue)
    txtDOB.Text = _currentProfile.DOB.ToString();
```

Note that if *there is* a value you can use it. Your original code seems to be backwards.

Comment: Or:   if (_currentProfile.DOB != null)

Comment: @SteveWellens - Sure, but if you already have a `Nullable<T>`, might as well use the built in semantics.

Comment: Sure, but if you go to the trouble of making something nullable, you might as well use it as something that can have a value of null.

Comment: @SteveWellens - I truly don't have strong feelings about it. A matter of style - something for a team to decide on and keep consistent in a codebase.

Comment: @Oded it didn't work for me with HasValue property, still was giving an error. I have used try{} catch{} syntax instead and pass another value if DateTime is null

Comment: @user1611620 - _What_ didn't work for you there? Is `DOB` a `DateTime?` or not?